# in pandas how to extract specific words from a sentence in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have df1, and I want to extract 'flavor' from the sentence in 'desc', and get df2. There is a flavor list that I decide which to pick according to the list. How can I get the result in python?

```
df1:
desc                                flavor
Coke 600mL and Chips                
Coke Zero 600mL and Chips           
390ml Coke + Small Fries            
600ml Coke + Regular Fries with     
Vanilla Coke 600mL and Chips        
Garlic Bread and pepsi 1.25ltr

df2:
 desc                               flavor
 Coke 600mL and Chips               Coke 
 Coke Zero 600mL and Chips          Coke Zero
 390ml Coke + SmallFries            Coke 
 600ml coke + Regular Fries with    Coke 
 Vanilla Coke 600mL and Chips       Vanilla Coke 
 Garlic Bread and pepsi 1.25ltr     Pepsi

> Flavor list: 
Coke 
Coke Zero 
Vanilla Coke 
Pepsi
```

Comment: How can you tell what is the flavor in a string? Garlic is not a flavor and Pepsi is a flavor? sounds strange.

Comment: How would you get result w/o python? Could you please give a bit more detail on how you decide what to extract / map in the given sentences?

Comment: @user1889297 Yes, I updated the question and make it clear.There is a flavor list and I map flavor according to the list.

Comment: @zipa I updated the question and make it clear. There is a flavor list and I map flavor according to the list.

Answer (score 4):

Use if want extract only one value by list use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
import re

L = ['Coke Zero', 'Vanilla Coke','Pepsi','Coke']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)

df['flavor'] = df['desc'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False, flags=re.I)
print (df)
                              desc        flavor
0             Coke 600mL and Chips          Coke
1        Coke Zero 600mL and Chips     Coke Zero
2         390ml Coke + Small Fries          Coke
3  600ml Coke + Regular Fries with          Coke
4     Vanilla Coke 600mL and Chips  Vanilla Coke
5   Garlic Bread and pepsi 1.25ltr         pepsi
```

If possible multiple `flavours` use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for lists and then [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['flavor'] = df['desc'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I).str.join(' ')

print (df)
                              desc        flavor
0             Coke 600mL and Chips          Coke
1        Coke Zero 600mL and Chips     Coke Zero
2         390ml Coke + Small Fries          Coke
3  600ml Coke + Regular Fries with          Coke
4     Vanilla Coke 600mL and Chips  Vanilla Coke
5   Garlic Bread and pepsi 1.25ltr         pepsi
```